# MySQL retrieving blob data by dividing it into pieces

Tags: php, mysql, swift, blob

I wonder if it's possible to retrieve the plot data from MySQL server via php by pieces. For example I have a video file stored in the database. I don't want to wait for the whole file to be downloaded to play it. For example in youtube, you don't need to wait for the whole file to be downloaded. It starts to play as soon as first few seconds are received.

Im working on a swift project where I need to download video file from my database and play it. I know how can I download it as whole but I need to download it by peaces and play it while downloading it at the background.

Comment: You can use `SUBSTR()` to return part of a blob.

Comment: While storing small files in a database is fine, I think you'd be nuts to store anything over 100k in anything other than a file system

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTR`.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(blobColumn, 1, 5000) AS first500bytes
FROM yourTable
WHERE <conditions>
```

Then the next query can return `SUBSTR(blobColumn, 5001, 5000)` to get the next block, and so on.

Comment: I see it mentioned in the comments section of the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html

Comment: This does not solve my problem. I edited the question to explain why

Comment: It seems like your question is more about the streaming process, not about querying the database.