# Download blob from mysql database with progressbar

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

I'm working on a Winform program where a user can download a large blob file. To visualize the progress I have added a progressbar on the form.
Downloading the blob works fine, but I can't figure out how to update the progress bar during download.

This is what I have so far...

```
        Private Sub frmMeldingNieuweVersie_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        
        ProgressBar1.Minimum=0
        ProgressBar1.Maximum=100
        ProgressBar1.Value=10
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    
        
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
            Dim objReader As MySqlDataReader
            Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MySqlConnectionString").ToString()
            dim filename As String = "setup.exe"
            dim setupFile As String
            Dim strLatestVersion As String
            Dim bytesLoad As Byte()
    
            Try
                myCmd.Connection = myConnection.Open
                myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT setupFile, OCTET_LENGTH(SetupFile) AS FileSize FROM Versiebeheer ORDER BY Versienummer DESC LIMIT 1"
                objReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader
    
                While objReader.Read
                    'BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(e.percentProgress)
                    If objReader.HasRows Then
    
                        strLatestVersion = Replace(objReader("Versienummer"),".","")
    
                            If Not IsDBNull(objreader("setupFile")) then
                                bytesLoad = DirectCast(objReader("setupFile"), Byte())
                                setupFile = "C:\Temp\" & filename
                            End If
                        objReader.Close()
                        objReader = Nothing
                    End If
    
                End While
                
                myConnection.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                myConnection.Close()
            End Try
        End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        Invoke(Sub()
            Me.ProgressBar1.Value = 50'e.ProgressPercentage
        End Sub)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        'Close()
    End Sub
```

Is it possible to make a progress bar for this problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Isn't the large blob read from the database in one go and not in chunks, so it isn't possible to have a progress bar to show progress?

Comment: This question may help you to move forward: [MySQL retrieving blob data by dividing it into pieces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283747/mysql-retrieving-blob-data-by-dividing-it-into-pieces). If you can download it in pieces, then you have an opportunity to update a progress bar

Comment: Rather than a progress bar, might be better to just show an animation.  Thing with progress bars in this context is you kind of need to know how big the file is before starting so you know how to increment it.  Might be a bit of a cop out but can save headaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for my problem. Here is the working code for the progress bar.
The reason why the backgroundworker didn't worked was because the WorkerReportsProgress was set to False.

```
    Private Sub frmMeldingNieuweVersie_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub
Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    ' Get the BackgroundWorker object that raised this event.
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker =
            CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    e.Result = RetrieveFile(worker, e)
End Sub
Private Function RetrieveFile(ByVal worker As BackgroundWorker, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) As Byte()
    Dim objReader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MySqlConnectionString").ToString()

    Try
        myCmd.Connection = myConnection.Open
        myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(SetupFile) AS fileSize, setupFile FROM Versiebeheer ORDER BY Versienummer DESC LIMIT 1"
        objReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)

        While objReader.Read

            If objReader.HasRows Then

                Dim memory As New MemoryStream
                Dim startIndex As Long = 0
                Const ChunkSize As Integer = 256
                Dim totalSize As Long = objReader("fileSize")
                Dim progressPercentage As Integer

                Do
                    Dim buffer(ChunkSize - 1) As Byte

                    Dim retrievedBytes As Long = objReader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, buffer, 0, ChunkSize)

                    memory.Write(buffer, 0, CInt(retrievedBytes))

                    startIndex += retrievedBytes

                    progressPercentage = (startIndex / totalSize) * 100
                    worker.ReportProgress(progressPercentage)
                    lblPercentage.Invoke(New SetValueDelegate(AddressOf SetValue), New Object() {progressPercentage})

                    If retrievedBytes <> ChunkSize Then

                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop

                myCmd.Connection.Close()

                Dim data() As Byte = memory.ToArray()

                memory.Dispose()
                Return data

            End If

        End While


        myConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        myConnection.Close()
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged

    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

End Sub

Public Delegate Sub SetValueDelegate(ByVal value As Integer)

Public Sub SetValue(ByVal value As Integer)
    lblPercentage.Text = value.ToString() & "%"
End Sub
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Dim bytesLoad As Byte()
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker =
            CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100

    Dim filename As String = "C:\tmp\setup.exe"
    bytesLoad = e.Result
    Using fs As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
        fs.Write(bytesLoad, 0, bytesLoad.Length)
        'Set image variable value using memory stream. 
        fs.Flush()
        fs.Close()
        btnInstalleerUpdate.Enabled = True
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the majority of the processing is not in the `While objReader.Read`, but in the `objReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader`.

While the SQL is being executed, your worker thread is idly waiting. It has no time to report Progress.

I see several methods to solve this

- main thread starts a `System.Timers.Timer`. This is the easiest Timer. Whenever the timer elapses advance the ProgressBar one step
- main thread starts an extra BackgroundWorker that will report (fake) progress every second or so. Update the ProgressBar one step

The problem is, that as long as you don't really know how long your query will take, the value in the progress bar doesn't really show the progress.

I'm not familiar with fetching blobs. Is it possible to fetch the data in sub-blobs?
If so, every fetched subBlob is reported as progress.
If you start with calculating how many sub-blobs you expect, you can calculate the real progress.

### Luckily Bjorn M Showed how to divide the blob in pieces!

I edited his solution into this answer to enhance the formatting

**Thanks Bjorn!**

My VB is a bit rusty, so I'll show first the code in C#, and then Bjorns formatted code

```
const string sqlText = "SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(SetupFile) AS fileSize,"
   + " setupFile FROM Versiebeheer"
   + " ORDER BY Versienummer DESC"
   + " LIMIT 1";
using (var dbConnection = new DbConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        dbCommand..CommandText = sqlText;
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtLoginnaam.Text);
        dbConnection.OPen();

        var dbReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader(commandbehavior.SequentialAccess);
        while (dbReader.Read())
        {
            // still something to read
            var readData = ... // use DbReader to fill the read data

            // process the read data and notify about progress:
            ProcessReadData(readData); 
        }
    }
}
```

Or in VB-like format

```
myCmd.Connection = myConnection.Open
myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(SetupFile) AS fileSize, setupFile FROM Versiebeheer ORDER BY Versienummer DESC LIMIT 1"
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtLoginnaam.Text)            
objReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader(commandbehavior.SequentialAccess)

Do
    Dim buffer(ChunkSize - 1) As Byte
    Dim retrievedBytes As Long = 
        objReader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, buffer, 0, ChunkSize)                                                  
    memory.Write(buffer, 0, CInt(retrievedBytes))                        
    startIndex += retrievedBytes
    If retrievedBytes <> ChunkSize Then                              
       progressPercentage = (startIndex/totalSize)*100                           
       this.ReportProgress(progressPercentage)                                                   
Exit Do
```

Note for Bjorn: this code is to be executed by the BackgroundWorker. The BackGroundWorker does not know who started it, and thus should not access the ProgressBar.

The form that started the BackGroundWorker, subscribes to the ProgressReported event from the BackGroundWorkder. In the event handler the progressPercentage is read by the UI thread who can update the ProgressBar accordingly.

Comment: What I have done till now is looking at the idea of JayV. Chop the blob in pieces. I have done this with the following code:
`myCmd.Connection = myConnection.Open
   myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(SetupFile) AS fileSize, setupFile FROM Versiebeheer ORDER BY Versienummer DESC LIMIT 1"
   'myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtLoginnaam.Text)
   objReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader(commandbehavior.SequentialAccess)`
...

Comment: `Do
      Dim buffer(ChunkSize - 1) As Byte

      Dim retrievedBytes As Long = objReader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, buffer, 0, ChunkSize)
      
      memory.Write(buffer, 0, CInt(retrievedBytes))

      startIndex += retrievedBytes

      If retrievedBytes <> ChunkSize Then
       progressPercentage = (startIndex/totalSize)*100
       'ProgressBar1.Value = progressPercentage
       worker.ReportProgress(progressPercentage)
       'BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progressPercentage)
       Exit Do
      End If
     Loop`

Comment: Still have to figure out the working of the backgroundworker.